# How to load a new php page in same window, using jQuery, and at the same time post data to it

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have this code:
1. FILE 1 - `test1.php`:

```
---- PHP CODE ----
<html>
-----HTML CODE ----
<script>
var someComplexObject; //This is a very large and complex JSON object 
                     //with lots of string and array data in it
  $.ajax({
    url: "test2.php",
    data: ({
      'data1': 3,
      'data2': 1,
      'data3': 1
    }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

    }
  });
</script>
</html>
```

2. FILE 2 : `test2.php`:

```
$somevar = json_decode($_POST['someComplexObject']);
--------PHP CODE TO PROCESS $somevar ----------
```

I want the `test2.php` page to open after some event in `test1.php` and object `objQuestionBank` should get `POST`-ed(I do not want to use `GET` method) to it so that I can process it on `test2.php`.

Is there some existing jQuery function to implement this.
Do i have to maintain some kind of client-side session variables, and if so then HOW?
I do not want to use Cookies

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You can just using a form to past the data to the page you want to process it, if you don't want to show this form, you can set it hidden... And the trigger you can use javascript, when get your order, just using form.submit() to post your data.

Comment: How do i pass the 'someComplexObject' using forms?

Comment: what do you mean by  'someComplexObject'?

Comment: You pass json formate is just the same as post <input type='hidden' name = 'xxx' value='yyy'> for each json field.

Comment: In my first PHP file, I have an object with name 'someComplexObject'. I want to pass it to next PHP file. How do I accomplish this using forms?

Comment: You need to serialize/convert the object to a string before submitting it. You can use jQuery.param() for this.

$('#obj').val(jQuery.param(obj));

Answer (score 0):

in index.php inside a form

```
<a href='poupdate.php?id=$data'>click to send the data</a>
```

in poupdate.php
you need to put like

```
isset($_GET[id])

$_GET[id] to get the data
```

Instead use this code without using GET method

```
 //page1.php

     <form  name="form1" method="post">
     <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     echo'
        <div id="id1">'.$row['id1'].'</div>
        <div id="title" >'.$row['title'].'</div>
     <div id="editShow'.$row['id1'].'" class="td width4"  >
     <img src="image/edit.png" id="edit_show" onclick="EditLinkshow('.$row['id1'].');">
     </div>
     }';?>
     </form>
     <div  class="page2_container" ></div>



//script.js //this is the code that will handle the event

function EditLinkshow(id1) {
    $('.page2_container').slideDown(300);
    //get the data of the form based by id
    title=document.getElementById('title').value;
    id=document.getElementById('id1').value;
    //send the data to page 2
    param = "id1=" + id +"&title="+ title;
    $.post("page2.php", param, 
             function (data) {  
                    //display page2.php in the same window
                $('.page2_container').html(data);
            }               
          );
    }       

//page2.php
<?php
 $id = $_REQUEST['id1']; 
 $title = $_REQUEST['title']; 

 echo "<div>".$id;
 echo "\n"$title."<\div>";
?>
```

Comment: Like i said, data is a complex object and too long to send using GET

Comment: if that is the case you should use javascript events in a form , use  ajax to send data to another php file and by using jquey you can display the data in the same window